# Pimcore DataObject Events

Tags: symfony, pimcore, symfony-eventdispatcher

I am building an application using Pimcore ,an open source software built on the top of symfony framework.I have implemented event listeners to perform validations of data being specified for Data object fields.Into event listener I have implemented following event listeners.

1. **preUpdate**
2. **postCopy**

While performing copy action on object **postCopy** event should be triggered but event triggering sequence is not proper as while copying object **PreUdpdate** event gets triggered prior to **postCopy** event and thus functionality implemented into listener of  **postCopy** event does not get reflected.
Please assist me how I can stop trigger of **PreUpdate** event while copying DataObject .I had tried using **stopPropagation** method but it did not stopped trigger of **PreUpdate** event while copying object.Kindly suggest me an appropriate solution for it.